# Possible for webservice to send message from server to client?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible with HTTP 1.1 or webservices, but just want to double check with you guys (and thus will probably be switching this application to WCF).

I want to send a message from the server an asp.net webservice is running on, to the client consuming it.  Is this possible without polling (IE an interrupt based model)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WCF, you do have a thing called duplex bindings, which allows the server to call back into the client at a specific address.

See the [MSDN documentation on duplex channels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx) for a first impression of what those are.

I don't think you can do this with ASMX.

Marc

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to confirm with another person.  Anyone else sees this, if you want to use http for duplex communication, you can use the wsdualhttpbinding binding.  This opens 1 connection for messages to the server, and another one where it transparently polls the server.